# Can I configure docker so it looks for images on my registry without specifying the registry name?

Tags: docker

I've set up a docker registry and I've pushed a project called `hellodocker` into it. On another machine, I've logged in to my registry but when I try to pull, I have to use the full name: `mydockerregistry.com/hellodocker`.

Is there a way to configure docker to include my registry as a place it can download Not Found images from?

Comment: Don't forget that your local system is a pseudo repository too, and is addressed without the prefix... so the two would become confused / difficult to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose, but you can configure the docker engine with a registry mirror setting. From the `dockerd` CLI, that's the `--registry-mirror` flag. Or in /etc/docker/daemon.json, you can set:

```
{ "registry-mirrors": ["https://mydockerregistry.com"] }
```

When configuring the daemon.json, you'll need to reload the docker engine after applying the change. In the desktop GUI, this is an option on the screen. From Linux, you'll run `systemctl reload docker`.

This comes with two caveats:

1. The registry mirror is polled first, then the upstream docker hub is polled for an image on any failure. If the mirror responds with a bad or old image, the docker engine will gladly use it.
2. Images without a repository prefix come from the docker library, and the mirror will be searched for `mydockerregistry.com/library/hellodocker` rather than `mydockerregistry.com/hellodocker`. Therefore you'll need to:

   ```
   docker tag hellodocker:latest mydockerregistry.com/library/hellodocker:latest
   docker push mydockerregistry.com/library/hellodocker:latest
   ```

I've got a presentation covering mirroring and caching you may find useful at:

- Presentation: https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/registry/presentation.html
- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm7g0saAC9k

Comment: Hmmm, it comes with some caveats. Maybe I won't do it.